# docs.descendants is Loading empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

## Linq Code

```
                XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()));

    List<string> books = docs.Descendants("INTEL")
   .Select(x => new {
           Title = (string) x.Element("TITLE"),
           Author = x.Element("INTEL_AUTH")
        })
.Select(x => new {
           Title = x.Title,
           FirstName = (string) x.Author.Element("FNAME"),
           MiddleInitial = (string) x.Author.Element("MNAME"),
           LastName = (string) x.Author.Element("LNAME"),
        })
.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1} {2} {3}",
                           x.Title,
                           x.FirstName, x.MiddleInitial, x.LastName))
.ToList();
```

## XML ************************

```
   <Data xmlns="http://www.TestWebsite.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.TestWebsite.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2012-03-12">


   <Record userId="62972" username="j23" termId="99" dmd:surveyId="2144185">

   <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="COLLEGE" entryKey="Business" text="Business"></dmd:IndexEntry>

   <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="Business/Finance" text="Business/Finance"></dmd:IndexEntry>

   <INTEL id="20" dmd:lastModified="2012-02-09T13:01:09">   

        <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
        <TITLE> House Price Indices</TITLE>
        <VOLUME>32</VOLUME>
        <ISSUE>1</ISSUE>
        <PAGENUM>127-160</PAGENUM>
        <CONTYPE>Journal Article/Notes/Comments</CONTYPE>
        <SCALE></SCALE>
        <REFEREED>Refereed</REFEREED>
        <CLASSIFICATION>Discipline-based Scholarship</CLASSIFICATION>
        <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="20327331841">

            <FNAME>John</FNAME>
            <MNAME>M.</MNAME>
            <LNAME>Doe</LNAME>
        </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
        <PUBLISHER>Real Estate Economics</PUBLISHER>
        <AUDIENCE>International</AUDIENCE>
        <PUBLICAVAIL>Yes</PUBLICAVAIL>
        <PUBLICATION_CODE>Basic Research</PUBLICATION_CODE>
        <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
    </INTELLCONT>
    <INTELLCONT id="20327360512" dmd:lastModified="2012-02-09T13:01:09" dmd:startDate="2011-12-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">

   <STATUS>In Prep Not Yet Submitted</STATUS>

  <TITLE>Time on the Market over the Cycle: a Spatial Model</TITLE>

  <VOLUME></VOLUME>

  <ISSUE></ISSUE>

  <PAGENUM></PAGENUM>

  <CONTYPE>Journal Article/Notes/Comments</CONTYPE>

  <CONTYPEOTHER></CONTYPEOTHER>

  <SCALE></SCALE>

  <REFEREED>Refereed</REFEREED>

  <COPYRIGHT></COPYRIGHT>

  <CLASSIFICATION>Discipline-based Scholarship</CLASSIFICATION>

  <MERIT>Journal List</MERIT>

        <INTEL_AUTH id="13">
        <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>

        <FACULTY_NAME>62972</FACULTY_NAME>

            <FNAME>John</FNAME>

            <MNAME>M.</MNAME>

            <LNAME>Doe</LNAME>

            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

        </INTEL_AUTH>

        <INTEL_AUTH id="20327360514">

            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>

        <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>

        <FNAME>Erik</FNAME>

        <MNAME></MNAME>

        <LNAME>deWit</LNAME>

        <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

        </INTEL_AUTH>

            <INTEL_AUTH id="5">

        <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>

        <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>

        <FNAME>Xiao-Song</FNAME>

        <MNAME></MNAME>

        <LNAME>Liu</LNAME>

        <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

        </INTEL_AUTH>

        <PUBLISHER></PUBLISHER>

    <PUBCTYST></PUBCTYST>

    <PUBCNTRY></PUBCNTRY>

        <WEB_ADDRESS></WEB_ADDRESS>

        <EDITORS></EDITORS>

        <ISBNISSN></ISBNISSN>

    <AGENCY></AGENCY>

        <AUDIENCE>International</AUDIENCE>

        <PUBLICAVAIL></PUBLICAVAIL>

        <SEA_GRANT></SEA_GRANT>

        <SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM></SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM>

    <PUBLICATION_CODE>Basic Research</PUBLICATION_CODE>

        <ABSTRACT></ABSTRACT>

    <REVIEW id="20327360516">

            <CITATION></CITATION>

        </REVIEW>

        <FULL_TEXT></FULL_TEXT>


        <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>

        <DTM_EXPSUB>December</DTM_EXPSUB>

        <DTD_EXPSUB></DTD_EXPSUB>

        <DTY_EXPSUB>2011</DTY_EXPSUB>

        <EXPSUB_START>2011-12-01</EXPSUB_START>

        <EXPSUB_END>2011-12-31</EXPSUB_END>

        <DTM_SUB></DTM_SUB>

    <DTD_SUB></DTD_SUB>
        <DTY_SUB></DTY_SUB>
        <SUB_START></SUB_START>
        <SUB_END></SUB_END>
        <DTM_ACC></DTM_ACC>
        <DTD_ACC></DTD_ACC>
        <DTY_ACC></DTY_ACC>
        <ACC_START></ACC_START>
        <ACC_END></ACC_END>
        <DTM_PUB></DTM_PUB>
        <DTD_PUB></DTD_PUB>
        <DTY_PUB></DTY_PUB>
        <PUB_START></PUB_START>
        <PUB_END></PUB_END>

    </INTEL>


            <INTEL id="243" dmd:lastModified="2012-02-09T13:01:09" dmd:startDate="2011-04-01" dmd:endDate="2011-04-30">

    <STATUS>Submitted/Under Review</STATUS>

    <TITLE> shopping centers</TITLE>

    <VOLUME></VOLUME>
        <ISSUE></ISSUE>
        <PAGENUM></PAGENUM>
        <CONTYPE>Journal Article/Notes/Comments</CONTYPE>
        <CONTYPEOTHER></CONTYPEOTHER>
        <SCALE></SCALE>
        <REFEREED>Refereed</REFEREED>
        <ORIG_RESEARCH></ORIG_RESEARCH>
        <COPYRIGHT></COPYRIGHT>
        <CLASSIFICATION>Discipline-based Scholarship</CLASSIFICATION>
        <MERIT></MERIT>

             <INTEL_AUTH id="24223270914">

        <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>

        <FACULTY_NAME>62972</FACULTY_NAME>

            <FNAME>John</FNAME>
            <MNAME>M.</MNAME>
            <LNAME>Doe</LNAME>

        <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>
        </INTEL_AUTH>

        <INTEL_AUTH id="16">

        <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>

        <FACULTY_NAME>89176</FACULTY_NAME>

        <FNAME>yna</FNAME>
<MNAME></MNAME>
            <LNAME>vei</LNAME>

            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

            </INTEL_AUTH>

    <INTEL_AUTH id="917">

    <STUDENT_LEVEL>Graduate</STUDENT_LEVEL>

        <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>gyu</FNAME>
            <MNAME></MNAME>

        <LNAME>Zhou</LNAME>

                    <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

            </INTEL_AUTH>

            <PUBLISHER>JREFE</PUBLISHER>
        <PUBCTYST></PUBCTYST>
        <PUBCNTRY></PUBCNTRY>

            <WEB_ADDRESS></WEB_ADDRESS>
        <EDITORS></EDITORS>
        <ISBNISSN></ISBNISSN>

             <AGENCY></AGENCY>
        <AUDIENCE></AUDIENCE>
        <PUBLICAVAIL></PUBLICAVAIL>

          <SEA_GRANT></SEA_GRANT>
        <SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM></SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM>

           <PUBLICATION_CODE></PUBLICATION_CODE>
        <DESC></DESC>

           <ABSTRACT>of competing space.
```

Yes

```
        <DTD_EXPSUB></DTD_EXPSUB>

        <DTY_EXPSUB></DTY_EXPSUB>

        <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>

        <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>

        <DTM_SUB>April</DTM_SUB>

        <DTD_SUB></DTD_SUB>

        <DTY_SUB>2011</DTY_SUB>

    <SUB_START>2011-04-01</SUB_START>

        <SUB_END>2011-04-30</SUB_END>

        <DTM_ACC></DTM_ACC>

        <DTD_ACC></DTD_ACC>

    <DTY_ACC></DTY_ACC>

    <ACC_START></ACC_START>

    <ACC_END></ACC_END>

        <DTM_PUB></DTM_PUB>
        <DTD_PUB></DTD_PUB>
        <DTY_PUB></DTY_PUB>

        <PUB_START></PUB_START>
        <PUB_END></PUB_END>

    </INTEL>

    <INTEL id="24" dmd:lastModified="2012-02-09T13:01:09" dmd:startDate="2011-04-01" dmd:endDate="2011-04-30">

        <STATUS>Submitted/Under Review</STATUS>

        <TITLE> House Prices</TITLE>

    <VOLUME></VOLUME>
        <ISSUE></ISSUE>

    <PAGENUM></PAGENUM>
        <CONTYPE>Journal Article/Notes/Comments</CONTYPE>

        <CONTYPEOTHER></CONTYPEOTHER>

        <SCALE></SCALE>

    <REFEREED>Refereed</REFEREED>

    <ORIG_RESEARCH></ORIG_RESEARCH>

    <COPYRIGHT></COPYRIGHT>

    <CLASSIFICATION>Discipline-based Scholarship</CLASSIFICATION>

        <MERIT>Journal List</MERIT>

        <INTEL_AUTH id="225">

        <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME>62972</FACULTY_NAME>

            <FNAME>John</FNAME>
            <MNAME>M.</MNAME>
            <LNAME>aDoe</LNAME>

            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

        </INTEL_AUTH>

        <INTEL_AUTH id="20327348226">
            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>Piet</FNAME>
            <MNAME></MNAME>
            <LNAME>Eichholtz</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

    </INTEL_AUTH>

    <INTEL_AUTH id="20327348227">
            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>Thies</FNAME>
            <MNAME></MNAME>
            <LNAME>Lindenthal</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>

             </INTEL_AUTH>
        <PUBLISHER>AER</PUBLISHER>
        <PUBCTYST></PUBCTYST>
        <PUBCNTRY></PUBCNTRY>
        <WEB_ADDRESS></WEB_ADDRESS>
        <EDITORS></EDITORS>
        <ISBNISSN></ISBNISSN>
        <AGENCY></AGENCY>
        <AUDIENCE>International</AUDIENCE>
        <PUBLICAVAIL>Yes</PUBLICAVAIL>
        <SEA_GRANT></SEA_GRANT>
        <SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM></SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM>
        <PUBLICATION_CODE></PUBLICATION_CODE>
        <DESC></DESC>
        <ABSTRACT></ABSTRACT>
        <REVIEW id="20327348228">
            <CITATION></CITATION>
        </REVIEW>
        <FULL_TEXT></FULL_TEXT>
        <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        <DTM_EXPSUB></DTM_EXPSUB>

        <DTD_EXPSUB></DTD_EXPSUB>

        <DTY_EXPSUB></DTY_EXPSUB>
        <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
        <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
        <DTM_SUB>April</DTM_SUB>
        <DTD_SUB></DTD_SUB>
        <DTY_SUB>2011</DTY_SUB>
        <SUB_START>2011-04-01</SUB_START>
        <SUB_END>2011-04-30</SUB_END>
        <DTM_ACC></DTM_ACC>
        <DTD_ACC></DTD_ACC>
        <DTY_ACC></DTY_ACC>
        <ACC_START></ACC_START>
        <ACC_END></ACC_END>
        <DTM_PUB></DTM_PUB>
        <DTD_PUB></DTD_PUB>
        <DTY_PUB></DTY_PUB>
        <PUB_START></PUB_START>
        <PUB_END></PUB_END>

                    </INTEL>

            <INTEL id="280" dmd:lastModified="2011-05-24T15:31:40" dmd:startDate="2011-04-21" dmd:endDate="2011-04-21">
        <STATUS>Revising to Resubmit</STATUS>
        <TITLE>Hedonic Analysis of Price Elasticity of Demand: The Case of New Condominiums in Shenzhen, China </TITLE>
        <VOLUME></VOLUME>
        <ISSUE></ISSUE>
        <PAGENUM></PAGENUM>
        <CONTYPE>Other</CONTYPE>
        <CONTYPEOTHER>Manuscript</CONTYPEOTHER>
        <ORIG_RESEARCH></ORIG_RESEARCH>
        <COPYRIGHT></COPYRIGHT>
        <CLASSIFICATION>Discipline-based Scholarship</CLASSIFICATION>
        <MERIT>Journal List</MERIT>

        <INTEL id="20327342081">

            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>

        <FACULTY_NAME>62972</FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>John</FNAME>
            <MNAME>M.</MNAME>

            <LNAME>Doe</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>
        </INTEL_AUTH>
        <INTEL_AUTH id="20327342082">
            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>Yong</FNAME>
            <MNAME></MNAME>
            <LNAME>Chen</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>
        </INTEL_AUTH>
        <INTEL_AUTH id="20327342083">
            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>Dogan</FNAME>
            <MNAME></MNAME>
            <LNAME>Tirtiroglu</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>
        </INTEL_AUTH>
        <PUBLISHER>Journal of Housing Economics</PUBLISHER>
        <PUBCTYST></PUBCTYST>
        <PUBCNTRY>The Netherlands</PUBCNTRY>
        <WEB_ADDRESS></WEB_ADDRESS>
        <EDITORS></EDITORS>
        <ISBNISSN></ISBNISSN>
        <AGENCY></AGENCY>
        <AUDIENCE>International</AUDIENCE>
        <PUBLICAVAIL>Yes</PUBLICAVAIL>
        <SEA_GRANT></SEA_GRANT>
        <SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM></SEA_GRANT_PROJECTNUM>
        <PUBLICATION_CODE>Basic Research</PUBLICATION_CODE>
        <DESC></DESC>
        <ABSTRACT></ABSTRACT>
        <REVIEW id="20327342084">
            <CITATION></CITATION>
        </REVIEW>
        <FULL_TEXT></FULL_TEXT>
        <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        <DTM_EXPSUB></DTM_EXPSUB>
        <DTD_EXPSUB></DTD_EXPSUB>
        <DTY_EXPSUB></DTY_EXPSUB>
        <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
        <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
        <DTM_SUB>April</DTM_SUB>
        <DTD_SUB>21</DTD_SUB>
        <DTY_SUB>2011</DTY_SUB>
        <SUB_START>2011-04-21</SUB_START>
        <SUB_END>2011-04-21</SUB_END>
        <DTM_ACC></DTM_ACC>
        <DTD_ACC></DTD_ACC>
        <DTY_ACC></DTY_ACC>
        <ACC_START></ACC_START>
        <ACC_END></ACC_END>
        <DTM_PUB></DTM_PUB>
        <DTD_PUB></DTD_PUB>
        <DTY_PUB></DTY_PUB>
        <PUB_START></PUB_START>
        <PUB_END></PUB_END>
    </INTEL>
    <INTEL id="20327340032" dmd:lastModified="2012-02-09T13:01:09" dmd:startDate="2011-03-01" dmd:endDate="2011-03-31">
        <STATUS>Submitted/Under Review</STATUS>
        <TITLE>Empirical estimation of the option premium for residential redevelopment </TITLE>
        <VOLUME></VOLUME>
        <ISSUE></ISSUE>
        <PAGENUM></PAGENUM>
        <CONTYPE>Journal Article/Notes/Comments</CONTYPE>
        <CONTYPEOTHER></CONTYPEOTHER>
        <SCALE></SCALE>
        <REFEREED>Refereed</REFEREED>
        <ORIG_RESEARCH></ORIG_RESEARCH>
        <COPYRIGHT></COPYRIGHT>
        <CLASSIFICATION>Discipline-based Scholarship</CLASSIFICATION>
        <MERIT>Journal List</MERIT>
        <INTEL_AUTH id="20327340033">
            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME>62972</FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>John</FNAME>
            <MNAME>M.</MNAME>
            <LNAME>Doe</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>
        </INTEL_AUTH>
        <INTEL_AUTH id="20327340034">
            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>Katsiaryna </FNAME>
            <MNAME></MNAME>
            <LNAME>Salavei</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>
        </INTEL_AUTH>
        <INTEL_AUTH id="20327340035">
            <STUDENT_LEVEL></STUDENT_LEVEL>
            <FACULTY_NAME></FACULTY_NAME>
            <FNAME>S. K. </FNAME>
            <MNAME></MNAME>
            <LNAME>Wong</LNAME>
            <INSTITUTION></INSTITUTION>
        </INTEL_AUTH>
        <PUBLISHER>RSUE</PUBLISHER>
        <PUBCTYST></PUBCTYST>


    <PUBCNTRY></PUBCNTRY>
    -01-01</PUB_START>
        <PUB_END>2004-12-31</PUB_END>
    </INTEL>
</Record>
 </Data>
```

I added Part of the XML that gets loaded to the doc.Load(response) part. Please check and

I added Part of the XML that gets loaded to the doc.Load(response) part. Please check and

I added Part of the XML that gets loaded to the doc.Load(response) part. Please check and

Comment: Any chance you could add some of the XML as well?

Comment: You are ignoring the namespaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the casing is correct because I'm sure XDocument is case sensitive and in your code sample you have "Intel" where as is in your comment below you have "INTEL"?

**EDIT**

OK, the other thing that it could be, this has caught me out in the past is the namespace declaration.

Check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604680/xdocument-descendants-not-returning-any-elements) and see if it helps.

**EDIT**

Using your XML I can do the following :

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Temp\Test.xml");
 XName name = XName.Get("INTEL", "http://www.TestWebsite.com/schema/data");
 var nodes = doc.Root.Descendants(name);
 foreach (var node in nodes)
 {
       Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
```

And it prints the value of each "INTEL" node .  However, I did have to fix the xml a bit to get it to work, I'm guessing because your XML is actually rather large there were some issues with the closing tags so I closed those and then XDocument could load the file.

I'm not too sure why you are not getting any results if you are using similar code for returning the descendants, it appears your original question text has disappeared :(.

Comment: Yes. I checked and the casing is Correct.

Comment: I added the name space next to qualified name. It didn't work

Comment: @SmilingLily Could you please add at least a cut down version of your XML please?

Comment: @SmilingLily Updated answer again.

Comment: Even this code didn't work. I am getting all the xml from as a response stream. (I am getting the correct XML , closing tags ..etc may be my Typhos). I don't know what I am doing Wrong :(

Comment: So if you use the code I posted above up until the foreach loop but instead of loading from file you use your response stream, the nodes variable is still empty?

Comment: Yes. When I type docs.root.descendants() or docs.root.descendantNodes() I can see all the nodes in the Watch window But If I Type  docs.descendants("INTELLCONT") I am getting    -  docs.Descendants("INTELLCONT") {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.GetDescendants} System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement> {System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.GetDescendants}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8795/discussion-between-smilinglily-and-paulie-waulie)

Comment: In my opinion, answers like these should be upvoted by the OP, regardless of whether or not the answer actually helps. The answerer obviously spent a good amount of his time solely to help an avatar on the internets. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
//List<string> books = docs.Descendants("INTEL")

XNamespace ns = @"http://www.TestWebsite.com/schema/data";
List<string> books = docs.Descendants(ns + "INTEL")
```

Comment: I am getting below error  Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I left out the remainder of the query (`.Select(...)`. And add `ns` to all element names.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question doesn't use the namespace. You say you've now tried it, but as you haven't updated the question with the new code, it's not at all clear *what* you've tried.

I prefer using the `XNamespace` type and the `+` operator, rather than calling `XName.Get`, but basically either way should work. Here's a short but complete program *showing* it working:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.TestWebsite.com/schema/data";
        var query = doc.Descendants(ns + "INTEL");
        Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); // Prints 1
    }
}
```

XML (just a cut down version of what's in the question):

```
<Data xmlns="http://www.TestWebsite.com/schema/data" 
    xmlns:dmd="http://www.TestWebsite.com/schema/data-metadata" 
    dmd:date="2012-03-12">
 <Record userId="62972" username="j23" termId="99" dmd:surveyId="2144185">
   <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="COLLEGE" entryKey="Business" text="Business">
   </dmd:IndexEntry>

   <INTEL id="20" dmd:lastModified="2012-02-09T13:01:09" />
 </Record>
</Data>
```