# How can i get Mulitiple subnode values using Linq to xml?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I got the Webservice Reponse in xml.

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <SmallImage>
      <Url>http://xxx<url>
      <height></height>
      <weight></weight>
    </SmallImage>
    <LargeImage>
      <Url>http://xxx<url>
      <height></height>
      <weight></weight>
    </LargeImage>
    <ItemAttributes>
      <Binding>Apparel</Binding>
      <Brand>Calvin Klein Jeans</Brand>
      <Department>mens</Department>
      <Title>Calvin Klein Jeans Men's Rusted Antique Skinny Jean</Title>
    </ItemAttributes>
    <SimilarProducts>
       <SimilarProduct>
         <ASIN>B0018QK10E</ASIN>
         <Title>New Balance Men's M574 Sneaker</Title>
       </SimilarProduct>
    </SimilarProducts>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Here, All i need to show the Title.
   Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title

I tried like this.

```
           #region Product Title
        var Title = xd.Descendants(ns + "Item").Select(b => new
        {
            PTitle = b.Element(ns + "ItemAttributes").Element(ns + "Title").Value
        }).ToList();
        #endregion
```

But It returns Object null. Please Let me know you need more information.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look here how to use the namespace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604680/xdocument-descendants-not-returning-any-elements

Comment: @AmiramKorach I tried like this: XName xn=XName.Get("Title","http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05");
            var title=from ft in xd.Descendants(xn)
                      select new
                      {
                          Ptitle=ft.Element("Title").Value

                      };
But nothing.,

Comment: You need to add it to every call to Descendants and Element. Make a little search about it and learn.

Comment: @AmiramKorach I Solved that myself., Thanks.,

Answer (score 0):

You need proper xml namespace name to search Element in LINQ Query.

You can get xmlnamespace:

```
XNamespace ns = xd.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;
```

and use ns in your LINQ Query.

or try,

```
var Items = xd.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Item");
var ItemAttributes = Items.Descendants().Where(b => b.Name.LocalName == "ItemAttributes");
List<string> Titles = ItemAttributes.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName == "Title").Select(o => o.Value).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
var Title = xd.Descendants(ns + "Items").Elements(ns + "Item").Select(BTitle => BTitle.Elements(ns + "ItemAttributes").Select(BTitle1 => (string)BTitle1.Element(ns + "Title")).FirstOrDefault() ?? "Null").ToList();
```

Comment: Care to add some comment to your solution? How does it works? How does it answer OP question?

Comment: What are you asking. Are you asking for the meaning of _OP_? Check [this meta link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op)